# Projection matrix implementation

Tags: c++, opengl, math, matrix, projection

I'm trying to build my own Rasteriser/Graphics pipeline (mimicking OpenGL) from scratch and I'm having problems with implementing a working perspective projection matrix. This is my current attempt:

```
template<typename T>
Matrix<T,4,4> Perspective(T fov,T aspect, T near, T far)
{
    T mat00 = 1 / (aspect*tan(0.5f*fov));
    T mat11 = 1 / tan(0.5f*fov);
    T mat22 = (-near-far)/(near-far);
    T mat32 = (2*near*far)/(near-far);
    T data[] = 
    {
        mat00,     0,     0,    0,
        0    , mat11,     0,    0,
        0    ,     0, mat22,mat32,
        0    ,     0,     1,    0
    };
    return Matrix<T,4,4>(data);
}
```

This is then passed to the vertex processing which performs the following:

```
    printf("Vertex inital:");vert.Print();
    vert = vert* m_ModelMatrix;

    printf("Vertex model:");vert.Print();
    vert = vert* m_ProjectionMatrix;

    printf("Vertex projection:");vert.Print();
```

The output of which is (for a randomly selected vertex):

```
Vertex inital:(1.000000,0.000000,-1.000000,1.000000)
Vertex model:(-1.900000,-2.300000,2.599999,1.000000)
Vertex projection:(-3.669604,-5.552692,2.405004,2.599999)
```

The above vertex corresponds to one of the vertices in this triangle:
[image]

My problem is the projection matrix appears to be completely wrong. When I *increase* the Z translation the triangle moves diagonally towards the **top-right** corner while appearing smaller, when I *decrease* the Z value the triangle moves diagonally towards the **bottom-left** corner while appearing larger. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

For reference, my implementation of the vector*matrix operation:

```
template<typename T,unsigned int length>
Vector<T,length> Vector<T,length>::operator* (const Matrix<T,length,length> & matrix) const
{
    T temp[length];
    memset(temp,0,length*sizeof(T));
    const T * matrixData = matrix.GetData();
    //For each row in the matrix & in the returned vector...
    for(unsigned int iRow = 0; iRow < length; ++iRow)
    {
        //For each column in this vector & matrix...
        for(unsigned int iColumn = 0; iColumn < length; ++iColumn)
        {
            temp[iRow] += m_Data[iColumn]*matrixData[iRow*length + iColumn];
        }
    }
    return Vector<T,length>(temp);
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just use [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/) instead of writing everything from scratch?

Comment: That projected (clip-space) vertex is not what you are showing in your screenshot. The coordinate `(-3.669604,-5.552692,2.405004,2.599999)` is actually outside of your viewport (and thus, part of this triangle should be clipped) -- you can tell this because X and Y are both < -W_clip (**-2.599999** in this case). It also sounds like you are forgetting to divide by W, which is what does the perspective scaling.

Comment: @Borgleader For the same reason I'm writing my own Rasteriser in the first place:the experience of writing my own! Otherwise +1, glm is the way to go.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman The vertex data I posted is taken from the vertex "shader" part of my pipeline. The divide by W step takes place in the rasterisation step.

Comment: @Davors72: Right, but if you actually had a working viewport transform, that triangle would be well off to the lower-left hand side. Just looking at the clip-space coordinates I can tell you that much. `(-1.41, -2.136, 0.925)` is well outside the normalized device coordinate range.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I think you are right my viewport matrix looks completely wrong! Matrix is as follows: 
`400.000000 0.000000 0.000000 400.00000      
  0.000000 320.000000 0.000000 320.000000  
  0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000  
  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000`

Comment: @Davors72: That actually looks right assuming everything is in column-major order. But your projection matrix is row-major. Have you tried transposing your viewport matrix?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Transposed my viewport matrix, it gives a similar result to the old viewport only this time the effect is reversed. Increasing the Z value moves the triangle to the bottom left of the screen (while appearing smaller), and decreasing the Z value moves it towards the top-right corner (while appearing larger).

Comment: Are you dividing by W before or after the viewport transform?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Before

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong then. About all I can really say is that if you are trying to mimic OpenGL, there are a few things you are doing that are actually more like D3D than OpenGL: row-major matrices, NDC Z should range from -1 to 1, not 0 to 1 (as your viewport matrix suggests), the traditional OpenGL projection matrix has m23 = -1 (this flips the Z-axis and changes right-handed view-space into left-handed clip-space).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks for your help, I think my problem is far deeper than just the projection matrix. I've moved my question to another post to reflect this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383949/implementing-graphics-pipeline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came back to this project after quite some break and I realised that my projection divide (aka /w) was only dividing the xyz coords. So when I applied the screenspace matrix the translate column was being multiplied by the 'greater than one' W value causing the triangle to move to the upper right as Z decreases.